# GridView going out of page asp.net

Tags: asp.net

`GridView` is going out of page... it goes further out in edit mode... here's the code for the gridview :
How do I get it to stay within the page (even in edit mode)...

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    AutoGenerateEditButton="True" DataKeyNames="EmployeeID" Visible="False" 
            Width="900px">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="EmployeeID" SortExpression="EmployeeID">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("EmployeeID") %>'></asp:Label>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("EmployeeID") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="FirstName" SortExpression="FirstName">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FirstName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FirstName") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="LastName" SortExpression="LastName">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("LastName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("LastName") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DOB" SortExpression="DOB">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DOB") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DOB") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Address" SortExpression="Address">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Address") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Address") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ContactNo" SortExpression="ContactNo">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ContactNo") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ContactNo") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="EmailID" SortExpression="EmailID">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("EmailID") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("EmailID") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DesignationID" SortExpression="DesignationID">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox7" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DesignationID") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DesignationID") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Designation" SortExpression="Designation">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox8" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Designation") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Designation") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Department" SortExpression="Department">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox9" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Department") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Department") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DepartmentID" SortExpression="DepartmentID">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox10" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DepartmentID") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DepartmentID") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DOJ" SortExpression="DOJ">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox11" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DOJ") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label13" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DOJ") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ReportsTo" SortExpression="ReportsTo">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox12" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ReportsTo") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label12" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ReportsTo") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Here's the screenshot
[image: my gridview]

any suggesstions that might work?

Comment: A common way to acheive this type of functionality is to apply fixed widths for each column (using CSS) then again in CSS apply overflow:hidden on the TD elements and finally (if you need to) add a span around the content within the TD and set the TITLE to be the same as the content so that when you mouse over the TD it will show the full text in a tool-tip style popup.

Comment: You could also drop non-essential columns (Like the Id columns unless you need them) and concatenate columns i.e. remove "First name"/"Surname" columns and then use a new column called "Name" with both the firstname and surname values within that one new column.

Comment: no non essential columns unfortunately.. & i dont like the idea of setting a fixed column width... also, i dont think it will help in edit mode (when the columns become texboxes)...
cant i get a scrollbar in the gridview?...

Comment: You could wrap a DIV around the TABLE and set the DIV to have a fixed width with the scroll:auto in CSS then you'd see a scroll bar on the div and the table inside.

Comment: around the table or around the gridview..? the gridview is in a particular column of the table, so...

Comment: Sorry around the GridView ;o)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked:

```
  <div style="width:90%;overflow:auto"> 
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    AutoGenerateEditButton="True" DataKeyNames="EmployeeID" Visible="False" style="width:100%;overflow:auto"
             HorizontalAlign="Center" >
```

Thnx...

Answer (score 0):

Set Width="100%" .Dont use pixel .

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    AutoGenerateEditButton="True" DataKeyNames="EmployeeID" Visible="False" 
            Width="100%">
```